# the rich man allocated funds

Tags: verbs, subjects

Is there anything semantically odd about the following sentence? I'm particularly interested in the compatibility between the subject *the rich man* and the predicate *allocated funds to the charity*.

> The rich man allocated funds to the charity.

Comment: Why allocated? The rich man ***gave money to charity***. The rich man ***funded the charity***. We don't say allocate funds to charity in this context. A company would allocate funds to specific projects, for example.

Comment: Allocate is like setting aside, if they changed the preposition to **for**, this sentence would make perfect sense. *The rich man allocated(set aside) funds for the charity. Glad I read your comment, though. I posted a reply that said this made sense, because my brain automatically inserted the word *for* instead of *to*

Comment: What if it was the rich man's charity, for example a private foundation? Then **to** would be OK.

Comment: That's true, I didn't consider that. I guess it's possible this sentence made perfect sense in context in that case.

Comment: Do you mean the man donated/gave some of his money to the charity?

Comment: @Element115 Why would "for" rather than "do" make the sentence acceptable to you?

Comment: This would make perfect sense in a situation where the agreement to give was separated from the actual payment. For example, if the rich man agreed to fund a charity in instalments over a period of time. When he first agreed the funding, he allocated the total amount, and then when each instalment was due he actually gave the money.

Comment: '...funds to charity' sounds better; without the definite article.

Answer (score 1):

There's a nuance of meaning here. If the rich man gave funds to the charity, the charity has the funds. If the rich man *allocated* them the funds, that means that he set aside money to give to the charity, but may or may not have given the money to the charity yet.

Comment: Agreed—I think "allocate" makes the most sense in a budgeting context. The man is deciding how to apportion a total amount of money, and decides some portion of it should go to the charity.

Answer (score 0):

The one who allocates has the authority *to allo*t (see what [that means](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/allot)) fund, funding, money, charity, or whatever it may be. A reach man can do it, so he's capable of doing it. I think it does fit what you mean by

> the compatibility between the subject the rich man and the predicate
>   allocated funds to the charity

***In addition:***

The verb "to allocate" also collocates with the preposition "for"-- as Element115 has noted, thanks to them--the use of the prepositions, the example sentences see [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=allocate+to%2Callocate+for&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Callocate%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Callocate%20for%3B%2Cc0), if you please.

Comment: But "a rich man" is not a term that denotes authority; words like "government," "mayor," "committee," "dean" do. That's why I suspect "a rich man" does not fit in well with the verb "allocate."